# Rails single line if else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to write a single line if else statement in a view.

```
<%= collection.name ? collection.name : @miniature.name %>
```

I want it to put collection.name if one exists, otherwise I want it to put @miniature.name

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To make it even clearer, you can use logical `OR` and `ActiveSupport's` [`Object#presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) (to put `collection.name` only if it exists and isn't blank):

```
<%= collection.name.presence || @miniature.name %>
```

If you want to display `collection.name` if it's not `nil`, but it's blank (empty string or string containing only whitespace), it will be enough to have:

```
<%= collection.name || @miniature.name %>
```

Comment: This seems a very elegant way of doing it. I didn't realise you could use presence like that.

Comment: @WorldOfProper you can, because in case object is blank, `presence` returns `nil`, which is treated like `false` in any logical statements.

Comment: What was that downvote for? Please give explanation.

Answer (score 30):

Check for the presence of `collection.name` first.

```
<%= collection.name.present? ? collection.name : @miniature.name %>
```

Comment: Ternary operator - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428708/remembering-the-ternary-operator-syntax

Comment: Yes I know - I just was referencing for the OP if he wanted to research

Comment: `if nil` won't throw any error, it will behave exactly like `if false`.

Comment: Still, where do you expect this error to be thrown?

Comment: @TheChamp it's true, but here, `name` can't be 'undefined'. What's more, if it could, your solution wouldn't work, you would probably have to use `defined?`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have

```
<%= collection.name ||= @minature.name %>
```

To those who downvoted - [Set Ruby variable if it is not already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671442/set-ruby-variable-if-it-is-not-already-defined)

Comment: Sorry I was writing as a conversation - let me change

Comment: I don't understand. This won't do what OP expects (display `collection.name` or `@miniature.name`) but will do what OP doesn't expect (set `collection.name` to `@miniature.name` if `@collection.name` is `nil`).

Comment: I believe my answer provided a valid answer to the OP

Comment: Your edited answer is valid, but it still may be surprise to OP that it also SETS `collection.name` to `@miniature.name` if it's `nil`. OP didn't specify this in requirements. Of course, I know the meaning of `||=` syntax, but I think it's not relevant here.